# нужно чтобы при парсинге выводило без 'api'

Tags: python

```
import requests

url = 'https://login.kundalik.com/login'

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url)

data = {
    'login':        'мой логин',
    'password':         'мой пароль',
}

d = s.post(url, data=data, headers=dict(Referer=url))
dd = s.get('https://kundalik.com/')
print(dd.text)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно в вопросе.В `print(dd.text)` вы выводите текст html страницы, что хотите делать дальше?

Comment: Вы бы лучше удалили свой пароль и логин из открытого доступа. Форумы не лучшее место для их распространения. И смените пароль.